# Does SQL Server insert rows into a table from a table that has no rows?

Tags: sql-server

This may seem like an odd question, but what I'm doing is joining a bunch of tables together to form say, table 'a', and from this result, I need to insert these values into another table say, table 'b'.  If table 'a' ends up having no rows, not even one that is NULL, will no rows be inserted into table 'b'?

Comment: Correct, if there are no rows to insert, you code will try, see there is nothing to insert then move on to the next thing if you have additional code.

Answer (score 2):

The insert trigger(s) will be called (if any will be existing and will be enabled), but no new records will be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

> If table 'a' ends up having no rows, not even one that is NULL, will no rows be inserted into table 'b'?

Yes if there is no row to insert then nothing will be inserted into the table 'b'